# Returning a string with only vowels capitalized

Tags: javascript

I'd like to return the variable newString with only vowels capitalized.  Not sure how to proceed.  Tried using an if/else block but my logic wasn't correct.

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var strCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + 1;
    var strLetter = String.fromCharCode(strCode);
    newArray.push(strLetter);
    var newString = newArray.join("");
    }
  return newString;
}

LetterChanges("hello");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is different from your approach, but you can do this:

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[aeiou]/g, function(l) {
    return l.toUpperCase();
  });
}

console.log(LetterChanges("The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog"));
```

---

Here's an approach that's closer to your attempt and uses somewhat simpler concepts:

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var ch = str.charAt(i);
        if ('aeiouAEIOU'.indexOf(ch) !== -1) {
           newArray.push(ch.toUpperCase());
        } else {
           newArray.push(ch.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    return newArray.join("");
}
```

Comment: This was great but my apologies, don't think I asked my question properly.  How could I incorporate that functionality into my existing function?  Right now I have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modifying it using the following algorithm: Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

Answer (score 3):

Split, map, join.

```
var vowels = 'aeiou';
var text = 'my random text with inevitable vowels';

var res = text.split('').map(function(c){
    return (vowels.indexOf(c) > -1) ? c.toUpperCase() : c;
});
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo6j89wv/1/

Comment: Your example input doesn't have any capital letters. :)

Answer (score 1):

Strings are Collections of word-characters, so you can directly access each part of the string:

```
var foo = 'bar';
console.log(foo[0]); // outputs 'b'
```

Hence you can extend this to uppercase the output:

```
console.log(foo[0].toUpperCase() // outputs 'B'
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this without regex, you can set the string to lower case, then iterate once over, calling toUpperCase() on each vowel.

```
function letterChanges(string){
  var vowels = 'aeiou';
  var lowerString = string.toLowerCase();
  var result = '';
  for( var i=0; i<lowerString.length; i++){
    if( vowels.indexOf( lowerString[i] ) >= 0 ){ //if lowerString[i] is a vowel
      result += lowerString[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result += lowerString[i]
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
const vowelSound = string => {
    let res = string.split("").filter(item => item === 'a' || item === 'i' || item === 'e' || item === 'o' || item === 'u')
    return res.join("")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. Also, please make use of the formatting possibilities we provide to make your code more readable. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Comment: It's just simple methods I used. No explanation is necessary, splitted filtered and joined , you want more ?